# RHEL 6 Partition Size

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I want to install RHEL 6 in my PC and would like to know the best partition size for different file systems.

Config:

> Hard Disk - 1TB
>   RAM - 16GB
>   Processor - i7 8700 [**UEFI**]
>   Motherboard - Gigabyte B360

I already have Windows 10 in it and would like to know how to dual boot Windows 10 and RHEL6. 500GB is already used by Windows.

Answer (score 0):

1. it depends on your intentions and needs with rhel6. A basic installation just needs a few Gb to work.
2. Do you explicitly need release 6 (why not consider using rhel7 instead)? RHEL-6 is currently in the last development phase where almost only security fixes are implemented, and is going EOL by 2020... (see [rhel life cycle](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/errata/))

Comment: For practicing Clustering and few other concepts...

Comment: Except if explicitely needing release 6, I would still encourage moving to 7 that will be maintained for long years...

Comment: Ok, I will go for 7 , Could you please let me know an approximate idea for ( for the config specified) the FS space ( which all FS needs to be created explicitly?).

Comment: If you need it just for a try I would create a partition with at most 10Gb, and use automatic partitionning scheme using LVM. Once installed you'll still be able to create additionnal partitions and refine mount points according to your needs.